# 'Use of extraneous &' in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to change a variable inside a dict that is itself inside a dict.

My dict is called `words[]` and inside it I have four dicts.
It is defined as such:

```
var words: [Int: [String: Any]] = [:];
```

And when adding variables to it, it is as such:

```
["order": Int]
["points": Int]
["used": Int]
["name": String]
```

Checking the variable works, but changing it (i.e. using `words[5]!["points"] += 5;`) gets me an error message `Use of extraneous '&'`.
This error does not appear if I were to define `words[]` as `var words: [Int: [String: Int]] = [:];` and omitting the "name"-string. So I think the problem lies somewhere in the use of `Any`.

Any ideas as to why this occurs? Am I just missing something glaringly obvious as a newbie?

Comment: 1. Don't use `;` in Swift. 2. You can't do what you want without more casting due to the use of `Any`.

Comment: `+=` is not defined for `Any`

Comment: words[5]!["points"]  returns Any and you cant use += operator with any and Int 5

Comment: RajeshKumar provides the solution, but this data structure indicates a major problem. Instead of `[Int: [String: Any]]`, this looks like it should be an array of structs or possibly a dictionary of ints to structs. If you find `Any` in a property (or escaping a function in almost any way), you've almost certainly done something wrong, and need to restructure your data. Otherwise you get insane syntax like what's described here.

Comment: @RobNapier In my understanding I can't create structs dynamically using strings, right? I'm filling my dicts from a for loop reading from a txt file. Would structs work for this somehow anyway?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dynamically using strings." As long as the data is structured somehow, it can be modeled in structs. Are the keys "order" "points" "used" and "name" consistent from row to row? (If not, how do you know what types they are?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`words[5]!["points"]` returns `Any` and you cant use the `+=` operator with `Any` and Int 5. You can use like this

```
if let points = words[5]?["points"] as? Int {
  words[5]?["points"] = points + 5
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I also tried `words[5]?["points"] as? Int += 5`, but it didn't work. I get a `Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'Int?'`. Why wouldn't that approach also work?

Comment: Because the subscript isn't the last step. The last step is an `as?` cast. The result of that is an `Int?` rather than a subscript reference that can be translated into a setter. You're going to have lots of subtle "why does it work this way but not that way" if you use Any, and particular Any in a Dictionary, which introduces the dreaded `Any?` type (which is a truly cursed type in Swift...)